# How do I programmatically stop all synths?

Tags: supercollider

How do I programmatically tell supercollider to stop all synths, as in the equivalent of `Ctrl+.` in the IDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have SC booted at the moment, but `s.freeAll` should do the job, as it frees all nodes attached to the server.

http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Server.html#freeAll

Answer (score 5):

You can all Ctrl+. from code directly:

```
    CmdPeriod.run
```

This is more complete than s.freeAll as it also stops language-side Threads, including the one that contains this command.  To see how to have threads escape CmdPeriod, check out the helpfiles for CmdPeriod and for SkipJack